# Do any items or skills boost weapon switch speed?

Tags: borderlands-2

I enjoy fighting with some elemental effects on my side but they're not always the most powerful weapon I have on hand. Sometimes I like to start with some potentially weaker but elemental gun then switching to a higher DPS variant to finish the bad guys off... particularly with slag weapons (for obvious reasons).

Maybe it's just the fireaxe Pyro in me, but I feel like my weapon switch speed is way slow and not suited to this type of play. Is there any item or skill that I use to bump the weapon switch speed a bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gunzerker's Quick Draw skill does this:

> Quick Draw - Tier 1: Gives you +7% Weapon Swap speed and +2% Critical Hit Damage per level.

His Gun Lust tree has a couple other skills that take effect on weapon swap too, so if you like constantly changing weapons he's your man. I'm not aware of any relics or class mods that affect reload speed (though a COM with + Quick Draw would do the trick)

Slag is really best as a grenade or when there are other players, so swapping isn't necessary, but if you really think it's worth it, Salvador's got the best skills for swapping. Of course the Siren has better skills for actually inflicting slag, if you really just want to inflict slag I'd say Maya's Flicker is more helpful.

Also note weapon swap speed is a hidden stat for the gun. You may just be using guns with horrible swap speed; Rocket Launchers in particular are bad for that, pistols swap quite quickly. Not sure if there are brand differences in that regard.

Comment: I believe Axton has the best weapon switch speed increases.  With Expertise (Tier 1, Gunpowder) you get "+14% weapon swap and aim speed per level; +7% movement speed when aiming per level."

Comment: @Kexlox does he? I'll have to check his tree. I don't play either so I went off a google search since I knew Salvador had something like this

Comment: http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Expertise  That said, Axton doesn't have anything that synergizes off a weapon swap.  But if the question is pure speed, I think Axton wins.